# Using array from private access specifier

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, private

Here I have an array within the private section of my class which is unable to retain the values set in different members of the clas; during the fight sequence both of the values in the array equate to 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<math.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class champions {
private:
    int health_array[2] = { };
    int attack_array[2] = { };
public:

void health_attack_set() {
    int health_set{};
    int attack_set{};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        health_array[i] = health_set;
        attack_array[i] = attack_set;
    }
}
void fight_sequence(int random_champion, int random_opponent) {
    cout << "FIGHT\n\n";
    while (health_array[random_champion] > 0 or health_array[random_opponent] > 0) {
        (health_array[random_opponent] -= attack_array[random_champion]);
        if (health_array[random_opponent] <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        (health_array[random_champion] -= attack_array[random_opponent]);
    }
    if (health_array[random_champion] > 0) {
        cout << "CHAMPION 1 WINS!!!";
    }
    if (health_array[random_opponent] > 0) {
        cout << "CHAMPION 2 WINS!!!";
    }
    if (health_array[random_champion] == 0 && health_array[random_opponent] == 0) {
        cout << "NO ONE WINS!!";
    }
} 
void champion_1() {
    health_attack_set();
    health_array[0] = 400;
    attack_array[0] = 150;
}
void champion_2() {
    health_attack_set();
    health_array[1] = 500;
    attack_array[1] = 100;
}
};
int main() {
    champions fight;
    fight.fight_sequence(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe it may be a simple mistake but hard to spot; thank you for any help that is given.

Comment: Where are "different objects" in "unable to retain the values set in different objects"?

Comment: Where do you call `champion_1()` or `champion_2()`?

Comment: champion_1 and champion_2 are the different objects. The values I have set in these objects aren't processed outside the object ex: (health_array[0] = 400).

Comment: `champion_1()` and `champion_2()` are functions that are never called.

Comment: Do I need to call them somewhere, I believed I could just set the values set in the objects and then since the array is in a private section it would be stored for the rest of the class to use.

Comment: You need to read a basic textbook on C++.    Your code only has one object of type `champions` (created in `main()`).    While you believe that `champion_1()` or `champion_2()` are objects, nobody can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm guessing you intended to declare the arrays [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Comment: This structure is just trouble. `champions` should be `class champion` as in `std::vector<champion>` where **each champion has their own properties**. What you're doing here is missing the point of objects almost completely.

Comment: I am sorry everyone I used the wrong terminology, I meant members of the class not objects.

Comment: To improve the readability of this code consider using things like `x -= y` instead of `x = x - y`. There's a lot of unnecessary verbosity here.

Comment: Here's an [example of using C++ classes more effectively](https://gist.github.com/tadman/ec7bca5b2f27582187ba4cc6af036b14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems are coming from not understanding how to structure your code in the presence of classes and multiple objects. I have restructured your code below in a cleaner and more common way (it is not the only way to do it, but it is more typical). Hopefully there are not typos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<math.h>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Champion{
public:
    int health;
    int attack;

    Champion(int health_, int attack_) : health(health_), attack(attack_) {
    }
};

void fight_sequence(Champion& champion, Champion& opponent) {
    cout << "FIGHT\n\n";
    while (champion.health > 0 || opponent.health > 0) {
        (opponent.health -= champion.attack);
        if (opponent.health <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        (champion.health -= opponent.attack);
    }
    if (champion.health > 0) {
        cout << "CHAMPION 1 WINS!!!";
    }
    if (opponent.health > 0) {
        cout << "CHAMPION 2 WINS!!!";
    }
    if (champion.health == 0 && opponent.health == 0) {
        cout << "NO ONE WINS!!";
    }
}

int main() {
    Champion champion_1(400, 150);
    Champion champion_2(500, 100);

    fight_sequence(champion_1, champion_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but is it not possible to incorporate an array because I would like to add more factors to the fight (ex: resistance). An array (if possible) may help to have the stats of each champion in the same place (like a member of a class).

Comment: @EvanBain Just add a member variable to the `Champion` class, just like `health` and `attack`  shown in this example?

Comment: To do that you would just add a new member to the class such as `int resistance;` below `int attack;`.

Comment: Thank you I am a new learner and appreciate all the help I got.

Comment: Note: There are design patterns that would have arrays for each property such as health, attack, and resistance. However, they are beyond your ability level based on what you have posted. I hope you don't take that as an offense - you need to start somewhere and those design patterns are not the right spot. If you are curious and want to read about those kind of patterns, look up "Data Driven Design" and "Entity Component Systems" after you have become more comfortable with programming in general.